# Rails 3.2 with ruby 1.9.3 invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII issue

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8

Is there somebody to help me with this issue that's driving me nuts for days...

In fact. I've upgraded my rails config to 3.2 and ruby to 1.9.3 and since then my jquery file is not working anymore giving me an error that is:

invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII

After a lot of tries I've found that this line is causing the problem:

```
rates.push(new Array('<%= tva_rate.id %>', '<%= tva_rate.tva_taux %>', '<%= tva_rate.tva_code %>'));
```

and I think that is the < and > characters... Problem is that I need these to make the code working... I've tried to add:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

but it does work...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmm, is that where you're actually getting that error? It doesn't look like there's any non-ASCII characters there. Also what is `config.encoding` set to in `config/application.rb`?

Comment: I'm getting the error trying to open the views that are using this javascript file (located in the assets).

Comment: and here is the config encoding Andrew:config.encoding = "utf-8"
Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Nope I've never run across this issue in this context, and what you've done is usually enough to remedy these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after one week of investigation, I finally solve this problem. This could be interesting for you to know that the problem was not directly the javascript code BUT the data it refers to...

In fact, in the corresponding table I have a record with an "é" character causing the problem... It means that when you update from Ruby 1.8... to Ruby 1.9... you have to clear your data from invalid characters before updgrading.

Then if you re-create the entry in the database after the update all working like a charm.

Hope it could help.

Dan

Answer (score 0):

You may add to your .bashrc

```
export RUBYOPT=-Ku
```